# Updating and Sorting a Multidimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a mySQL query that dumps into an array, is sorted and then displayed, and that works perfectly.

My problem is that I want to update these values, re-sort them and display. I've been able to update the values, but it's within the same for loop and so it doesn't re-sort. So then I close the loop and re-sort but it doesn't save the updates I made in the first loop. Help is much appreciated.

```
foreach ($arr as $mks){
if ($mks['Column1']==$Var) {$mks['Column2'] = $mks['Column2'] + 1;
}
```

My sorting code

```
foreach ($arr as $mks){
    echo $mks['Column1'] . ", " . $mks['Column2'] . "<br>";
}
```

---

How do I get this to re-save into my array properly?! I've tried googling this for most of the morning but has lead to frustration.

Comment: have you saved the changes into a new array and then echo'd the new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $mks){
    if ($mks[$key] == $Var) {
        $arr[$key] = $mks+1;
    }
}
```

Now, `$arr` will contain the modified array, and you can use / modify it further as you need.

Comment: Thank you, a variation of this answer is what worked for me. I ended up:


foreach ($arr as $key => $mks){
if ($mks['Column1']==$Var) {$arr[$key]['Column2'] = $mks['Column2'] + $1;}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "sorting code" but you can try to use references "&" instead of copy vars in your foreach(s) :

```
foreach($arr as & $mks){
...
}
```

Instead of copying your cells it will to give you a reference and every modifications done on it will be *saved* in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your array like this instead

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $mks){
    if ($mks['Column1']==$Var) {$arr[$key]['Column2'] = $mks['Column2'] + 1;
}
```